# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while counting special characters a string

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I was writing a code that counts special characters in a string prompt from the key board. This is the method.

```
public static int specislChar(String s){
    int counter = 0;
    char ch;
    for (int i =0 ; i<=s.length(); i++){
        ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || ch != ' ') {
            System.out.print(" " + ch);
            counter++;
        }           
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Every time I call this method,  at the `System.out.print()` it gives me an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 20

Answer (score 1):

your loop should be less than `i<s.length()`. it is the cause of `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` and you have to use `AND` operator not `OR`

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) && !Character.isSpaceChar(ch)) {
        System.out.print(" " + ch);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When debugging this kind of issues, always run you code step by step and check if what you wrote is doing what you expect at every step, it's a simple but invaluable technique :)

If you want to count chars that are not letter/digit/space, this:

```
|| ch != ' '
```

will always give true for every character that is not space, the check you need to to is this one:

```
if ( !(Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || (ch==' ')) ){
```

Or, applying [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if ( (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) &&  (ch!=' ') ){
```

Comment: i thank u all for your help it helped. @uraimo@npinti@Exbury@Nama Gala

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop condition from `<=` to `<` to solve `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` as array index start from 0 so it will go upto length-1.

```
i < s.length();
```

And use `&&`(And) operator instead of `||`(Or) operator in `if` condition as you want to check both the conditions.

```
if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) && !Character.isSpaceChar(ch) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is due to this line: `for (int i =0 ; i<=s.length(); i++){`. In Java, arrays are 0 based and run from 0 to `n-1`, where `n` is the amount of entries you have.

Thus, changing it to `for (int i =0 ; i<s.length(); i++){` will remove the error.

Also, this: `|| ch != ' '` will be true for any non special character as well, which will cause inaccurate results. I think you mean `&& ch != ' '`.

Answer (score 0):

**Example code:**

```
public class ____QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This should be 11
        System.out.println("Number of special characters: " + 
                specialChar("asdaskd12312!@(#(!@#)(*asdas12301230"));

        // This should be 8
        System.out.println("Number of special characters: " + 
                specialChar("!a@b#c$d%e aaa bbb ccc !!!"));
    }

    public static int specialChar(String s) {

        // Get rid of alphabets, digits and space
        s = s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
        return s.length();
    } 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number of special characters: 11
Number of special characters: 8
```

- A much simpler way would be to remove all alphabets, digits, and space
- The remaining content will be the special characters

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :-

```
public static int specislChar(String s) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray())
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) && ch != ' ')
                counter++;
        return counter;
    }
```

**Input** :- `%@%^&*(hi hello$!!+ #`

**Output** :- `12`

Answer (score 0):

you are looping though `i<=s.length();` but it should be `i<=s.length()-1;` because index starts at 0. If it starts at 0 then it should be only to length-1